# Get start and stop indexes of overlapping matches?

Tags: python, regex

I need to know start and end indexes of matches from next regular expression:

```
pat = re.compile("(?=(ATG(?:(?!TAA|TGA|TAG)\w\w\w)*))")
```

Example string is `s='GATGDTATGDTAAAA'`

`pat.findall(s)` returns desired matches `['ATGDTATGD', 'ATGDTAAAA']`. How to extract start and end indexes?
I tried:

```
iters = pat.finditer(s)
for it in iters:
    print it.start()
    print it.end()
```

However, `it.end()` always coincide with `it.start()`, because the beginning of my pattern starts fro `(?=` so it does not consume any string (I need it to capture overlapping matches). Obviously `pat.findall` extracted desired string, but how to get start and stop indexes?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your issue—it wasn't clear to me at first what you meant by overlapping matches. But, sometimes people make mistakes while earnestly attempting to help—and in light of that, I think your attitude is unnecessary. It's not hard to explain _politely_ how someone may have misunderstood you—most people, upon being told _politely_, become apologetic and seek to do right—sometimes even going through _greater_ lengths to do so than if they had _not_ misunderstood to begin with, out of a desire to make up for their mistake. By being rude, you forfeit all consideration.

Comment: Sorry if I was rude. I appreciate the desire to help.

Comment: I see you've deleted your other comments—maybe it's me who misjudged you—sorry myself for not taking more time to understand your question before posting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Tomalak said, the regexp engine has no builtin notion of overlapping matches, so there's no "clever" solution to be found (**which turned out to be wrong** - see below). But it's straightforward to do it with a loop:

```
import re
pat = re.compile("ATG(?:(?!TAA|TGA|TAG)\w\w\w)*")
s = 'GATGDTATGDTAAAA'
i = 0
while True:
    m = pat.search(s, i)
    if m:
        start, end = m.span()
        print "match at {}:{} {!r}".format(start, end, m.group())
        i = start + 1
    else:
        break
```

which displays

```
match at 1:10 'ATGDTATGD'
match at 6:15 'ATGDTAAAA'
```

It works by starting the search over again one character beyond the start of the last match, until no more matches are found.

### "Clever" or time bomb?

If you want to live dangerously, there's a 2-character change you can make to your original `finditer` code:

```
print it.start(1)
print it.end(1)
```

That is, get the start and end of the first (`1`) capturing group.  By not passing an argument, you were getting the start and end of the match as a whole - but of course a matching assertion always matches an empty string (and so start and end are equal).

I say this is living dangerously because the semantics of a capturing group *inside* an assertion (whether lookahead or lookbehind, positive or negative, ...) are fuzzy at best.  Hard to say whether you may have stumbled into a bug (or implementation accident) here!  Cute :-)

EDIT:  After a night's sleep and a brief discussion on Python-Dev, I believe this behavior is intentional (& so reliable too).  To find all the (possibly overlapping!) matches for a regexp R, wrap it like so:

```
pat = re.compile("(?=(" + R + "))")
```

and then

```
for m in pat.finditer(some_string):
    m.group(1)  # the matched substring
    m.span(1)   # the slice indices of the match substring
    # etc
```

works fine.

Best to read `(?=(R))` as "match an empty string here, but only if `R` starts here, and, if that succeeds, put the info about what `R` matched into group 1".  Then `finditer()` proceeds as it always does when matching an empty string:  it moves the start of the search to the next character, and tries again (same as what the by-hand loop in my first answer did).

Using this with `findall()` is trickier, because if `R` contains capturing groups too, you'll get all of them (can't pick & choose, as you can do with a match object such as `finditer()` returns).

Comment: @Tim Peters Interesting suggestion with two charachter change. I thought myself about it and I tried adding 0, because I thought I am matching the whole match! So in this case the whole group is empty but the subgroup is not :-)

Comment: @msh, exactly!  And that's exactly why I'd hesitate to rely on it:  the notion that there's a non-empty match inside an empty match just kinda screams "bug alert!" ;-)

Comment: @Tim Looks like I was right in theory and yet wrong in practice. .NET regexes do the same thing - you can extract the lengths of groups within assertions, even if the overall length of the match is 0.

Comment: @Tomalak, we're in the same boat there ;-) Trying to discuss it now on the Python-Dev mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

There are no overlapping matches in regular expressions.

Either you match something or you don't. Anything you match can only be part of *one* match/sub-match.

Look-aheads are ephemeral, they don't increase any real counters.

Comment: Your `.start()` and `.end()` indexes in `finditer()` return the same number because there are no overlapping matches in regular expressions. But there you go, you may believe something else.

Comment: If you edit your answer, I can undo downvote, otherwise the downvote is locked.

Comment: No, I won't. Maybe next time you take more time before casting down-votes.